# How to get a user's groups/places through API (can see in browser, not through API)

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This works: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me/groups

This doesn't: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=1234567890/groups
(where 1234567890 is someone who is not a friend, but is in or applying to a group I admin).

However, this works:
https://www.facebook.com/1234567890
and I can see their groups just fine.

QUESTION: Is there a way I can act-as-me or other permission to see someone's groups through an app?

This is likely a permissions/token thing - but I need to 'act-as-me' and see what I can see/have-rights-to.

END GOAL: I need to assist my rejecting of automated spammed join-requests. Easy to recognize who is fake, so I want to automate that. But, how can I have an app see what I see in FB (without screen scraping).

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you can see their groups publicly, you **can't** get their groups using the Graph API **unless** you have a valid Access Token from that user with `user_groups` permission.

The [documentation for the User Groups](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/groups) clearly says that:

> - A user access token with user_groups permission is required to view    the groups that person is a member of.
> - A user access token with friend_groups permission is required to view    the groups that person's friends are members of.

You can find more details about Access tokens [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/).

Comment: so - is there a non-screen-scraping-'way' of getting that info?

Comment: There's always a hack around to every problem. I don't know any of those methods as I've mostly used the API for my purposes. Also, I am not sure whether Facebook TOS and the [policies](https://developers.facebook.com/policy/) allow us to use these methods for collecting data.

Comment: purpose is to stop the automated fake requests coming my way. would like to think FB would let us automated our defense since the offense is automated.